# UINavigationBar layout warning after canceling a back swipe

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios9, uinavigationitem

I get the following warning on iOS 9 when canceling a back swipe in a navigation controller.

> Unexpected mismatch of left views and frames during navigation bar
>   layout. transition state = 0, item stack = (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "" ), frame count = 2, view count = 1

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Comment: So no idea, anyone?